# Where to put routers.py for database routing in a Django project

Tags: python, django

I am trying to put a routers.py file into a Django project so that my application will use two different databases: one for my external data, the other for the pages in my newly-installed Wagtail CMS.

Where in the file system should I put routers.py?
The file system currently looks like this:

```
projectname/
    projectname/
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    app1/
        admin.py
        apps.py
        models.py
        views.py
    app2/
        admin.py
        apps.py
        models.py
        views.py
    somedataloader.py
    requirements.txt
    logfile
```

Comment: Just put it under the `app` that is using the router is fine, isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I put mine in `projectname/projectname/`, parallel with `settings.py`, since I see it as a kind of setting. But you refer to it by its Python module path in `DATABASE_ROUTERS` so you could put it somewhere else if you prefer.